# Where to point external fan on graphics cards

Tags: graphics-card, cooling, fan

I was redirected to here to ask my question. I have two graphics cards running 24/7 along with a small fan to help keep them cool. One card is in the motherboard while the other is raised on a rack, there is no case so there is as much air flow as possible. So my question is, where should I keep my external fan at? A) on the side of the cards where the stock fans are located or B) on the opposite side of the fans.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used choice (C) - at one edge side, so that the air flow is split in two, and flows along both front and back. Looking down at the card, that would be 'T' shaped, where the fan is perpendicular to the card.

Comment: Didn't even cross my mind, thanks for the response

Comment: For the fan mounting, I used a piece of aluminum strapping from a hardware store. The kind that looks like a straight piece from an erector set, with regularly spaced holes. It's flexible and easy to mount a fan to it, to allow any orientation.